# Revert image from binary data python

Tags: python

I have a matplotlib plot saved as png file, I read the image as bytes and storing in database, How to revert the image after reading the binary file

My image is

[image]

saved in a location, reading it

```
image = open("./Plots/image1.png", 'rb').read()
```

saving in my database as

```
cbytesFile = zlib.compress(image)
base64File = base64.b64encode(cbytesFile)
dbData = {}
dbData["pic"] = base64File.decode('utf-8')
```

Now I read back the image

```
loaded_binary = base64.b64decode(dbData["pic"])
decompressed_binary = zlib.decompress(loaded_binary)
```

I tried

```
with open(decompressed_binary, "rb", encoding='utf-8') as imageFile:
    src = imageFile.read()
```

I get

```
ValueError: binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument
```

How to open the image and show / save?

Comment: Use an image library like Pillow or cv2 or matplotlib to read the image.

Comment: This Worked, fp = io.BytesIO(decompressed_binary)
with fp:
    img = mpimg.imread(fp, format='jpeg')
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()

Comment: Your `open(decompressed_binary...` line was clearly wrong, you were putting your data in place of the file name in open.